# Dafny Multiset of Bubblesort in List

Tags: list

I want to verify Bubblesort in a datatype List with ensuring the List is sorted.
I want to ensure that after the sorting the output List still contains the same elements as input List.
The outpust List has the same multiplicity of the elements as from the input List by using the Count function.
The functions are correctly implemented but i cant come up with the idea to verify the Contain and Count function in Bubblesort. Any idea?

```
datatype List = Null | Cons(head: nat, tail: List)

method sort(arr: List) returns (res: List)
{
  res := arr;
  var i := Length(res) - 1;
  while(i > 0)
  {
    var j := 0;
    while (j < i)
    {
      if(res[j] > res[j+1])
      {
        res[j+1] := Store(res, j, temp2);
        res[j] := Store(res, j+1, temp);
      }
      j := j+1;
    }
    i := i-1;
  }
}
```

I tried to ensure Count and Contain function in Store function but it seems it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Like, your other question they only thing that Dafny knows about a "method" is what you put into the post-conditions. In particular, you need to assert that the contents of the list are the same before and after the sorting.

```
function toMultiset(ls: List): multiset<nat> {
    if ls.Null? then multiset{} else multiset{ls.head} + toMultiset(ls.tail)
}
// Add this post condition to the Bubblesort method.
ensures toMultiset(arr) == toMultiset(res)
```

I have verified a few other versions of [sorting algorithms](https://github.com/hath995/dafny/tree/main/FunctionalAlgorithms) here for example.